# how to use c# code in the page source of custom newform of a list to update some fields of it

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I was looking for a solution where I'll populate the value from one list and display it to the another list. I have now got some code but not sure how use it.

I have to now use some c# code into page source of custom newform of a list. This code will actually retrieve the user information and update to the field in the custom newform in the list.

Following C# code I want to use in newform page source using sharepoint designer

```
   SPSite _site = SPContext.Current.Site;
   ServerContext serverContext = ServerContext.GetContext(_site);
   UserProfileManager myUserProfile = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
   UserProfile currentUserProfile = myUserProfile .GetUserProfile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

   string departmentName = (string)currentUserProfile["department"].Value;
   string managerName = (string)currentUserProfile["manager"].Value;
   _site.RootWeb.Dispose();
   _site.Dispose();
```

Please help me to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer removes various types of code, including all C#, in order to prevent vulnerabilities from accidentally being introduced. To use your C# code you will need to create and deploy a solution package with VIsual Studio. Instead, your best bet is probably to use JavaScript. [Here is documentation for 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920104.aspx), [here is a utility to simplify retrieving the data in 2010](http://spjsblog.com/2011/09/18/accessing-user-profile-information-in-sharepoint-with-javascript-updated-version/), and [here is some code that will get you very close to what you're trying to do.](http://www.sharemuch.com/2012/05/11/retrieve-sharepoint-user-profile-property-value-with-jquery/)

Copy of the code in case that link dies:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ensure system stuff is loaded before we start calling client object model
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");

// create context variables
var context = null;
var web = null;
var currentUser = null;

// this function calls object model to determine current user name
function getWebUserData() {
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();
currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
currentUser.retrieve();
context.load(web);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),  
Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}

// this function gets called if we get current user name successfully
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {
var loginName = web.get_currentUser().get_loginName();

// this call requests the value for property named "Title" for current user name
GetUserProperty(loginName, "Title");
}

// yes, things failed; I ignore it here but you can display an alert
function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {
// Unable to find user profile
} 

// function which retrieves the value of the property
function GetUserProperty(accountName, propertyName) {

// constructing the call to a user profile using web services
var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
  + '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
  + '<soap:Body>'
  + ' <GetUserPropertyByAccountName
   xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/UserProfileService">'
  + '  <accountName>' + accountName + '</accountName>'
  + '  <propertyName>' + propertyName + '</propertyName>'
  + ' </GetUserPropertyByAccountName>'
  + ' </soap:Body>'
  + '</soap:Envelope>'

// making a call with jQuery
$.ajax({  
url: '/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx',  
type: "POST",  
dataType: "xml",  
data: soapMessage,  
complete: displayProfileProperty,  
contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"" 
}); 
return false; 
}

// things went well and we get results back
function displayProfileProperty(xmlHttpRequest, status)  
{  
// the result is burried in XML markup so we look for the right node
$(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find('Values').each(function()  
{  
// get the text property of the node and display it
var name = $(this).find('Value').text(); 
alert(name); 
}); 
}
```