# where to put the C# code if you don't want to use WEB PART in SharePOINT via iSharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm site collection administrator for a site in SharePoint 2010. I'm using SharePoint Designer 2010.
I'm not allowed to use WebPart etc. I created a some HTML pages and Javascript files and using the LISTDATA.SVC to update my lists and uploading documents to my document library programmatically via Javascript.

Till here it's fine. Now when I click a button, I need to call a webservice (*.ASMX) file and need to use file.readallbytes and call the webservice with this bas64 encoding stuff etc. a 20 lines of C# code.

I can't write these in Javascript so I need to write this in C#, Which I already wrote, but where do I put my 20 lines of C#.NET code? There is no code behind file.

I just see default.aspx.... If I create default.aspx.cs file and add button event handler will this work or how can I get this working?

I can't change anything in Central Admin (not access to it). I've just full SCA right.

I googled and find something "PageParserPath" but it's not clear?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862025%28v=office.12%29.aspx

I've just 2 months exprience with SP, so please be more concreet when responding.

please advice where and how to put the C# code?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, [SharePoint designer removes almost all C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667566/how-to-use-c-sharp-code-in-the-page-source-of-custom-newform-of-a-list-to-update) that you put directly into the aspx page. You will need to either use Visual Studio to build a web part or find a JavaScript solution. What you're asking is very likely possible through JS, so you might consider posting a new question giving your C# code and asking for help doing the same thing with JS.